# APK is not installed on Android (When target Sdk Version in build.gradle is 28)

Tags: android, download, sdk, installation, failed-installation

I want to install the program I downloaded from my program, but when I put ***targetSdkVersion 25*** in build.gradle file, the ***apk is installed***, but when I put ***targetSdkVersion in 28*** in build gradle file, the ***apk will not be installed*** , and the program runs until the startActivity(intent) line but is not installed , and there are no error messages in logcat.

**File path APK**

```
"/sdcard/Android/data/com.****.****/Version/update.apk"
```

**in Manifests**

```
<application
            .....>

            <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.authorityStr"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
            </provider>
</application>
```

**in XML provider_paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="sdcard"
        path="Android/data/com.****.*****/Version/"/>
</paths>
```

**in build.gradle file**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28 //when change to targetSdkVersion 25 apk installed
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
```

**in java for install APK**

```
public static void InstallApk(String filename) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            if (file.exists()) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
                    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context, Context.getPackageName() + ".authorityStr",
                                file);
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                    intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android" + ".package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    Context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                    Context.startActivity(install);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(Variable.TagMessage, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: anything in logcat?

Comment: The program runs until the startActivity(intent) line but is not installed. The phone is Android 8.1. The same line of code runs on Android 6, and there are no error messages in logcat. Is there a problem or a bug in the code?   @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: DO you got any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: No, have you got a solution? @AbhishekBardolia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first add permission in Manifests file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

**in java for install APK**

```
public static void InstallApk(String filename) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            if (file.exists()) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
                    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context, Context.getPackageName() + ".authorityStr",
                                file);
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                    intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android" + ".package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                    Context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                    Context.startActivity(install);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(Variable.TagMessage, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```